# Bash break line with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

When I run this bash script below my results are all echoed on the same line, as "Example Output" below shows.

```
#!/bin/bash
Commander=$(nmap -vv -p 8080 xxx.149.xxx.100-xxx | 
            grep "Discovered open port 8080/tcp     on" | sed -r 's/^.{32}//');
echo $Commander;
```

Example Output:

```
xx.149.xx.115 xx.149.xx.107 xx.149.xx.107 xx.149.xx.101 xx.149.xx.118 xx.149.xx.146
```

What I would like is:

```
xx.149.xx.115 
xx.149.xx.107 
xx.149.xx.107 
xx.149.xx.101 
xx.149.xx.118 
xx.149.xx.146 
xx.149.xx.19
```

Any, Suggestions??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just quote your variable when calling it:

```
echo "$Commander"
```

#### Sample

```
$ myvar="hello
> i am fedor
> fedorqui"

$ echo $myvar
hello i am fedor fedorqui

$ echo "$myvar"
hello
i am fedor
fedorqui
```

---

So you have space separated output and you want it to be new line separated? If so, pipe to `tr ' ' '\n'`, that will do this replacement.

```
$ d="a b c"
$ echo "$d" | tr ' ' '\n'
a
b
c
```

Comment: I cant exactly go this route because of how nmap is piped to grep. What I thought would have to happen is insert a "\n" in the sed command but at this point not exactly sure??

Comment: Aaaah I think I misunderstood your question. So you have space separated output and you want it to be new line separated? If so, pipe to `tr ' ' '\n'`, that will do this replacement.

Comment: What I think I'm going to try is getting rid of sed and just use tr, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: echo $Commander | tr ' ' '\n';

Comment: Nice to read that, @Philcinbox : )